# Bitbake understanding the EXCLUDE_FROM_WORLD mechanism

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm developing on Yocto 2.4 rockowith a BSP given by my provider. I'm trying to build modemmanager from the meta-openembedded layer, included in the meta-oe sub layer.

The configure task fail and give me as error :

```
checking for gobject-introspection... 
configure: error: gobject-introspection-1.0 is not installed
```

After some search I've installed the libgirepository1.0-dev package on my host machine. But the error is always present.

I've continued investigations, and find in my recipe log the line :

```
DEBUG: EXCLUDE FROM WORLD: virtual:native:/home/test/share/sc20_linux/poky/meta/recipes-gnome/gobject-introspection/gobject-introspection_1.52.1.bb
```

I've tried to find which recipe excludes the dependency, with no success.

Can you help me to understand how works the EXCLUDE_FROM_WORLD mechanism ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that is debug output and doesn't mean the recipe is excluded. Have you looked at the modemmanager recipe to see if it has a DEPENDS on gobject-introspection-native and perhaps gobject-introspection? If not, or the PACKAGECONFIG isn't set, try adding the DEPENDS or enabling the PACKGECONFIG?

Also, have you tried simply building "bitbake object-introspection-native" and "bitbake object-introspection". You should get an error about why they ar disabled if you try and build them directly and they are excluded/disabled for some reason.

Comment: I don't know why but by adding in the recipe polkit the DEPENDS gobject-introspection and gobject-introspection-native, it's working now. polkit it's a direct dependency of modemmanager. And yes, you are right, it was a debug output! Thank you very much.